# Два DIV в ряд, один резиновый

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать без привлечения `JS` следующее? Есть два `div'a` расположенных в ряд, один принимает ширину контента, которая может быть разной при каждой загрузке, второй - резиновый и занимает всю оставшуюся ширину до границы родительского блока. Гугл даёт решения только для случаев, когда размер первого `div'a` фиксированный.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например используя [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) у родителя, [`flex: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex) у первого div'а и [`flex: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex) у второго div'а:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  flex: none;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">Текст нефиксированного размера</div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А если мне нужно будет расположить несколько таких строк одна под другой? Что-то не получается.

Comment: @АртёмСвистула несколько таких строк одна под другой, это вы блок `.parent` дублируете? Вроде должно работать

Comment: А в одном parent'e их разделить никак нельзя?

Comment: @АртёмСвистула думаю можно, но не очень понятно как именно надо, так что думаю лучше задать отдельный вопрос про это

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content minmax(min-content, 1fr);
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a a1">Какой-то длинный текст</div>
  <div class="a a2">Текст</div>
</div>
```